# why my dropdown menu is not working in the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

1. **
2. > this is my html code for menu and drop down menu is not working  and also whereare things that its not working properly.and this is
   >   part simple code and where it will be embedded with wordpress later
   >   onwards

   ```
   **     
   <div class="menu-logo">
                   <div class="container">
                   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                       <ul class="menu">
                           <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                       <ul class="submenu">
                                       <li><a href="#">LONG </a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">COST</a></li>
                                       </ul>
                           <li><a href= "#">ROOM</a></li>
                       </ul>

                   </div>

       **
   ```

> this is my css code for drop down menu.

**

```
        .menu-logo {
            margin-top: 9px;
            background: #999;
        }
        ul.menu {
            list-style-type: none;
            /* display: inline-block; */
            margin-top: 34px;
            position: relative;
        }
        ul.menu li {
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
            padding: 7px 12px 5px 12px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        ul.menu li a {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul.submenu {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            display: none;
            /* display: inline-block; */
        }
        ul.submenu a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
        ul.submenu a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
        }
        ul li a:hover ul.submenu {
            display: block;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submenu code will work when you place the **UL** tag in its parent **LI** tag

Like below::

```
<div class="menu-logo">
                <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                 <li><a href="#">LONG </a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">COST</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>           
                        <li><a href= "#">ROOM</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

and the css code changes to:

```
ul li:hover ul.submenu {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: try adding the below css also:  ul.submenu {top: 100%; left: 0; width: 200px;}